# Replacing SPST light switch with Occupancy sensor

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, motion-sensor

I have a standard single pole single throw switch and I am installing an occupancy sensor. The existing switch only uses  black wires on the switch, one on top one on bottom and the ground. The occupancy switch has one green for ground, one Red for Load and one black for line. Do I just put one black on RED one black on Black and green to ground?

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement!  Pictures would help us understand.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to determine which of the black wires on the original switch is the always hot feed. A voltage meter would be very helpful in determining this. Once you establish this, hook that black wire to the black,line, wire on your new switch. Hook the other black wire to the red, load, wire from your new switch and then hook up the ground wire to the metal box or to the bare copper wire.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked, I really appreciate your guidance.

Comment: @RickWilliams if you're happy with the answer please consider marking the answer as accepted. This will help us be more organized